# Java - Regex to split input text but keep delimiters

Tags: java, regex

Looking for some regex help. I'm looking for a method in Java to split up some input text by words, but also keep the delimiters (whitespace, punctuation). Another way to put it would be to split words into their own indexes and other non-word characters could be in other indexes of the array.

This input text:

```
"Hello, this isn't working!"
```

Should be put into an array like this:

```
{"Hello", ",", "this", "isn't", "working", "!"}
```

or

```
{"Hello", ", ", "this", " ", "isn't", " ", "working", "!"}
```

I've done basically the same thing in Python using this:

```
def split_input(string):
    return re.findall(r"[\w']+|[\s.,!?;:-]", string)
```

But I've yet to find a way to accomplish the same thing in Java. I've tried `String.split()` with lookahead/lookbehind and I've tried pattern matchers but haven't had much luck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If space is a delimiter then your text should product at least 4 elements isn't it?

Comment: Why do you want an array while you simply have one string in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` is not the Java analog to Python's `findall`. `Matcher.find` is.

```
Pattern stuff = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+|[\\s.,!?;:-]");
Matcher matcher = stuff.matcher("Hello, this isn't working!");
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(matcher.group(0)); // add match to the list
}
```

Comment: Ah, I did have a go using Matcher but didn't get too far. This seems to do the job quite well though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this : It is exactly what you wanted.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello, this isn't working!";
    String[] s = str.split("(?<=\\s+|,\\s)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
}
```

Output:

```
[Hello, , this , isn't , working!]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, putting aside your strange example, here is something that should suit your needs (yet to be tested):

```
"(?=[\\w']+|[\\s.,!?;:-])"
```

For the first version.

```
"(?=[\\w']+|[\\s.,!?;:-]+)"
```

To keep several delimiters as a whole.

The whole idea being, as you want to split but keep all the characters, to match positions only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way to do this but you can try :

```
string.replaceAll("([\\s.,!?;:-])", "$1\n");
string.split("\n");
```